# Android source generic product/device type differences

Tags: android, build, android-emulator, android-source

In the [AOSP tree](https://android.googlesource.com/) are basically 3 generic device types.

- List is `base path`: `PRODUCT_DEVICE`, `PRODUCT_NAME`
- `device/generic/<arch>`: `<arch>`, `mini_<arch>`
- `device/generic/qemu`: `generic_<arch>`, `qemu_<arch>`
- `device/generic/mini-emulator-<arch>`: `mini-emulator-<arch>`, `mini_emulator_<arch>`

What are the differences between and uses for `mini_`, `qemu_` and `mini_emulator_`?

**Edit:**
After googling a bit I didn't find a detailed explanation, but [this blog post](https://udinic.wordpress.com/2014/06/04/aosp-part-2-build-variants/) pointed out, that there are three more 'products' which are neither specific devices nor generic products: `full`, `aosp` and `sdk`. What do these do exactly?

**Edit 2:**
Looking into envsetup.sh from different ROMs (aosp, cyanogenmod, aospa) it seems to be possible, to set `TARGET_PRODUCT` to something like `aosp_<arch>` or `full_<arch>`. Is this an alias to one of `mini_`, `qemu_` or `mini_emulator_` or does this something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after digging through the android build system a bit more I think I got it now:

The following `TARGET_PRODUCT`s are allowed:

- `aosp_` is just an alias for `full_`. It accepts all architectures (`arm`, `x86`, `mips`, `arm64`, `x86_64` and `mips64`) and is also used for devices (e.g. `aosp_flounder`)
- `full_` is, if no device is specified via `aosp_`, a full featured build for the emulator. It includes `core_`. (`full` without `_arch` deaults to `arm`)
- `sdk_` is just an alias for `sdk_phone_`. (`sdk` without `_arch` defaults to `armv7`)
- `sdk_phone_` builds the Android SDK for the specific architecture. It includes `core_` too
- `generic_` is the basic Android platform not specialized for any board. It can build for `arm` (default if nothing specified), `x86` and `mips`. I don't think this can boot on a device or an emulator.
- `core_` is the basic configuration for all communication-oriented android devices like phones and tablets.
- `mini_` somehow extends `core_`. It seems to be a emulator build using only the basic configuration instead of the full featured build. But I'm not sure with this one.
- `mini_emulator_` combine `mini_` with goldfish and QEMU related files. It seems to be some basic emulator build too.
- `qemu_` is an absolutely minimal android build for qemu (not the android emulator). It just has the stuff necessary to boot and some command line utilities/libraries and adb.